# To find p-value of compounds (pairwise)

Tags: r, gene, snp, statistics

I have next `SNPs` data.frame structure

```
> str(SNPs)
'data.frame':   1703 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ group: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ rs1  : Factor w/ 3 levels "D/D","I/D","I/I": 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ rs2  : Factor w/ 3 levels "a/a","a/b","b/b": 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ rs3  : Factor w/ 3 levels "G/G","G/T","T/T": 2 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 ...
 ...other rs


> head(SNPs)
  group rs1 rs2 rs3 ...other rs
1     A D/D b/b G/T
2     A D/D b/b G/G
3     A I/D a/b G/T
4     A I/I b/b G/G
5     A I/I b/b G/G
6     A I/D a/b T/T
```

For example, I noticed that `rs5 4b/4a` and `rs6 G/G` in `group A` very often occur together (see below). In `group B` they very often occur together too. So I want to know - is it statistical regularity or not.

I can create table with all pairs in both groups

```
> SNPs$rs5_rs6 <- paste(SNPs$rs5, SNPs$rs6)
> tmp <- table(SNPs$rs5_rs6, SNPs$group)
> tmp

              A   B
  4a/4a G/G   1  20
  4b/4a G/G  31  83
  4b/4a G/T  14  51
  4b/4a T/T   1   0
  4b/4b G/G  37 106
  4b/4b G/T  35 119
  4b/4b T/T  11  31
```

So, now I need compare (find p-value) group A and group B: `4a/4a G/G` in group A vs `4a/4a G/G` in group B, `4b/4a G/G` in group A vs `4b/4a G/G` in group B, `4b/4a G/T` in group A vs `4b/4a G/T` in group B and etc. Only this pairs/

How can I do that?
I need p-values for all

```
> tmp

              A   B
  4a/4a G/G   1  20 - p-value?
  4b/4a G/G  31  83 - p-value?
  4b/4a G/T  14  51 - p-value?
  4b/4a T/T   1   0 - p-value?
  4b/4b G/G  37 106 - p-value?
  4b/4b G/T  35 119 - p-value?
  4b/4b T/T  11  31 - p-value?
```

Comment: If you can restate your question in terms of explicit null and alternative hypotheses it will be much easier for people to help you determine an appropriate test to find p-values

Comment: @heathobrien chisq - it is my choice. Problem is not to choice test. Problem is to calculate it for pairs in `tmp`

Comment: If your question is how to apply a chisq test to the above table, the answer is `chisq.test(tmp$A, tmp$B)`

Comment: heathobrien, my question is how to apply chisq test to `tmp` and get 7 p-values:
compare`4a/4a G/G` in group A vs `4a/4a G/G` in group B and get first p-value, compare `4b/4a G/G` in group A vs `4b/4a G/G` in group B and get the second p-value and etc.

Comment: OK. Now we're getting somewhere. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get standardised residuals from `chisq.test` and convert these to p-values, but it's [not recommended](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129194/converting-chi-square-adjusted-residuals-to-p-values). The frequencies of each genotype depend on the counts of all other genotypes, so the p-values aren't independent and they aren't corrected for multiple testing, but if you must:

```
pnorm(-abs(chisq.test(tmp[,c('A','B')])$stdres)))
```

Comment: hm... What other options are possible? whether the differences between the two groups were statistically significant for all pairs (rs5+rs6 and all pairs - 4a/4a G/G, 4b/4a G/G and etc)?

Comment: If I were you, I would just focus on the overall chisq p-value (corrected for the number of SNP pairs tested). The frequency of allele 2 depends on the frequency of allele 1 and the frequency of the genotypes depends on the allele frequencies, so I don't think it makes much sense to test each genotype independently

Comment: Note that all you're doing is looking at differences in linkage disequilibrium between groups. There are a lot of tools out there to that efficiently

Comment: chisq.test - not very good for values less then 5. I'v try to use fisher.test `pnorm(-abs(fisher.test(tmp[,c('A','B')], simulate.p.value=TRUE)$stdres))`, but I'v got the error - Error in abs(fisher.test(tmp[, c("A", "B")], simulate.p.value = TRUE)$stdres) :   non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: o the p-values aren't independent and they aren't corrected for multiple testing, but if you must - I'm not must. I just think it is good solution to use chisq.test. I just need to know - is there any differencies in two grops

Comment: Fishers exact test doesn't give you residuals. Having values less than 5 is probably the least of your worries if you're trying to obtain p-values for each combination of genotypes.

Comment: In that case, I'm completely confused and do not understand what I can do with my data and how...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80573/discussion-between-heathobrien-and-n-osennij).